# Generic Sorting

Tags: c#, generics

I have a many entities and and I want to write some generic sorting class which can provide me a sorted list on a given object and a property. e.g.

```
Class Country
{
      public int id { get; set; }
      public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I should be able to pass unsorted List to my sorter class along with property name on which it should be sorted. I have beat myself quite a while by now and got stuck now. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by a property name can be easily achieved using .NET `LINQ` extension methods, or more specifically, the Dynamic LINQ section. Take a look at [Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) written by Scott Gu regarding how it all works. Essentially your *sorter class* needn't be anything more than a fancy wrapper for the LINQ extension `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending`.

Here's an example:

```
var sortedCountries = listOfCountries.OrderBy("CountryName");
```

Alternatively, if you're familiar with generics, you could write a wrapper that accepts a collection, and a `Func<TSource, TKey>` used to select the properties value, like so:

```
public class MySorterClass
{
    public IEnumerable<TSource> OrderList<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource> list, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
    {
        return list.OrderBy(selector);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TSource> OrderList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> list, string propertyName)
    {
        return list.OrderBy(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, solution with generics makes more sense to me as I am not using LINQ in my project.

Comment: In your suggested solution, you're using `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending`, both of which are LINQ methods. I'd strongly recommend having a look at the dynamic LINQ stuff. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, take a look at [Collections.Sort(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). There are two versions, one I think uses that natural ordering of your elements to sort them (take a look at the [Compareable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)) interface, the other takes in a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Either should work. Otherwise I am sure other languages have something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

You didn't mention a language. In `c#` you can make your classes implement the interface `IComparable` and add `CompareTo` function, which take two args and return which one bigger, or use anonymous function that do the same.

Comment: Sorry to mention, I am using and I dont want to use IComparable thing too.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to implement the generic sorter and also makign that as an extension method so I can use it anywhere where I use List, below is my implementation. sortorder is Asc/Desc and propertyname is the name of property of type T. This works fine and I am happy with this.

```
public static List<T> SortedListWithLamda<T>(this List<T> list, string sortorder, string propertyname)
        {
            List<T> sortedlist = new List<T>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyname) && list != null && list.Count > 0)
            {

                Type t = list[0].GetType();

                if (sortorder == "A")
                {

                    sortedlist = list.OrderBy(
                        a => t.InvokeMember(
                            propertyname
                            , BindingFlags.GetProperty
                            , null
                            , a
                            , null
                        )
                    ).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    sortedlist = list.OrderByDescending(
                        a => t.InvokeMember(
                            propertyname
                            , BindingFlags.GetProperty
                            , null
                            , a
                            , null
                        )
                    ).ToList();
                }
            }
            return sortedlist;
        }
```

Comment: If this is your desired solution, you may want to consider changing the `sortorder` to be an `enum`, and also implement property checking on type `T`. :)